# insert new column into dataframe which computes from more than 1 variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to insert a new column into a dataframe based on the computations of the corresponding column,

This works for me:

```
df['new column'] = [ foo(x) for x in df['X']]
```

Now if we want to base the computations for > 1 column

```
df['new column'] = [ foo(x, y, z) for x, y, z in df['X', 'Y', 'Z']]
```

This is what i tried, but it doesn't accept the syntax.
I could u iterrows, but i would like to inline the computation.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access the underlying numpy array:

```
df['new column'] = [foo(x, y, z) for x, y, z in df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].values]
```

Beware, it may be what you want (and it is probably faster than iterrows or apply) but you have no access to index of column names from the numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processes per rows and lambda function for pass column names:

```
df['new column'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['X'], x['Y'], x['Z']), axis=1)
```